# How to fix: HAX is not working and emulator runs in emulation mode

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, emulation, haxm

I'm new to Android programming. I have 'Intel x86Emulator Accelerator(HAXM installer)' installed already.
The Emulator opens up but nothing else happens(just the black screen and android written on it).

### How do I fix this?

emulator: device fd:824

emulator: The memory needed by this AVD exceeds the max specified in your HAXM configuration.

emulator: AVD      RAM size = 1536 MB

emulator: HAXM max RAM size = 512 MB

Answer (score 0):

I use Genymotion, I think is better than this emulator, this is the link:
[genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/)

Answer (score 0):

emulator: ***The memory needed by this AVD exceeds the max specified in your HAXM configuration.***
emulator: AVD RAM size = 1536 MB
emulator: HAXM max RAM size = 512 MB

the information already told you why.

you'd better do adjustment as below:
repair the installation of HAXM(the package from Intel what you installed), and just only set the Ram to 1.5G(maximum is 1.9G).

(---reset your PC, I did it)

in your emulator in AVD, modify the Ram as 1G.

It should be OK